# How to fix Unknown provider: locationProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I written the code as my angular controller as below:

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) ，
```

But I always get this error:

```
angular.js:9193 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: locationProvider <- location <- activeNavDirectivehttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.3/$injector/unpr?p0=locationProvider%20%3C-%20location%20%3C-%20activeNavDirective    at 
/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12    at 
/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3473:19    at Object.getService [as get] 
/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3600:39)    at 
/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3478:45    at getService 
/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3600:39)    at Object.invoke 
/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3622:13)    at 
/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5146:43    at Array.forEach (native)    at forEach 
/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:300:11)    at Object.<anonymous> 
(xxxxx/js/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5144:13)angular.js:9193 (anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems somewhere you are using `$locationProvider` without the `$` prefix `locationProvider`. Can you check.